# Hittesting works fine but setting values to the same object results in error?

Tags: arrays, flash-cs5, flash-cs4, hittest, projectile

Im working on shooting some bullets and the collision testing works perfectly fine it even hurts the zombies. Except the one problem, i want the bullets to disappear when they hit a zombie this sounds easy sense Im already hit testing inside the "bulletContainer" Class, well long story short i call the bulletContain[a].killBullet(); and output dialouge says its not a function(I know for a fact its a function and the "bulletClass" Class it self is loading properly). It seems once i create the bullet to shoot it has a mind of its own and doesn't listen to any variables i change inside it for me to tell it needs to disappear/killBullet()

Heres Snippets of my code please comment if you feel like you need more(althought there isnt much)

```
BulletContainer Class(Showing Just testCollosion Function):

    //Collision Tester/////////////////////////////////////////////
        private function testCollision(){
            //Get number of bullets on screen
            var numBullets = bulletContain.length;

            //Define a local variable for ease of reference
            var localZombieContain = Object(root).zombieContain.zombieContain
            var numZombies:Number   = localZombieContain.length;

            //Loop through every bullet for collision test
            for(var a:Number = 0; a < numBullets; a++){
                //Loop through every zombie & hit test to see if bullet is hitting
                for(var b:Number = 0; b < numZombies; b++){
                    var killBullet:Boolean = false;
                    if(localZombieContain[b].hitTestObject(bulletContain[a])){
                        //Tell zombie it has been hit
                        localZombieContain[b].hurtZombie();

                        //Tell Bullet its dead for garbage
                        killBullet = true;
                     }

                     if(killBullet){

                         bulletContain[a].killBullet();
                         trace("BULLET DIED");
                     }
                }

            }
```

BulletClass(Showing everything from bulletClass):
(IGNORE REDENDENT SWITCH() CODES, THATS FOR LATER DEVELOPMENT USE)

```
package  com{
        import flash.display.*
        import flash.net.*
        import flash.utils.*
        import flash.events.*

    public class bulletClass extends MovieClip{
             public var dead = 0;

                    var moveBulletInt;
        public function bulletClass(type:Number) {
            //Declare bullet types from library
            var tmpBullet1 = new bullet1;

            switch(type){
                case 1:
                    addChild(tmpBullet1);
                break;
            }

            //Move this bullet
            moveBulletInt = setInterval(moveBullet, 10);
        }

        public function killBullet(){
            clearInterval(moveBulletInt);
            trace("BULLET DIED");
        }

        private function moveBullet(){
            if(dead == 0){
                this.x += 15 * Math.sin((this.rotation - 90) * (Math.PI / 180));
                this.y += 15 * Math.cos((this.rotation - 90) * (Math.PI / 180));
            }
            if(dead == 1){
                //clearInterval(moveBulletInt);
                this.x = -100
                this.y = -100
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was calling the movie clip instead of calling the class when i previously added bullets else where in my code. So i ended up just doing var newObject = newBullet; instead of the lather newObject.addChild(newBullet);

Comment: After two days you can select this as the correct answer to close out this question.